# Error migrating 32-bit Access 2013 DB to 32-bit SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database in 32-bit Access 2013 that I want to migrate to SQL Server Express. I've only installed the 32-bit version of SQL Server Express and I'm using the 32-bit version of Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access, but I get the error

> Access Object Collector error: Database
>        Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CD7791B9-43FD-42C5-AE42-8DD2811F0419} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154. This error may be a result of running SSMA as 64-bit
>   application while having only 32-bit connectivity components installed
>   or vice versa. You can run 32-bit SSMA application if you have 32-bit
>   connectivity components or 64-bit SSMA application if you have 64-bit
>   connectivity components, shortcut to both 32-bit and 64-bit SSMA can
>   be found under the Programs menu. You can also consider updating your
>   connectivity components from
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=197502.
>        An error occurred while loading database content."

Presumably it's finding *something* 64-bit *somewhere*, but I can't work out where to look. I've tried the obvious using the 64-bit version of SQL Server Express, but that gives the same message.

Where do I look next?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Access Database to MSSQL Database Using Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207427/converting-access-database-to-mssql-database-using-microsoft-sql-server-migratio)